# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘oracle-xe-11.2.0’: File exists unable to mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0: at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257

Tags: command-line, software-installation, oracle

it shows file alreaddy exists, when I run "sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm" coomand could anyine please help me?

Comment: if a file exists with that name, the system can't create a directory with the same name, so you'll have to `rm` the file for the code to run unaltered.  (rather than `rm` (remove) the file, you could `rename` (or `mv`) it to a different name (eg. add a .file or something to its name to make it unique & different).  note: I don't know or use your package..

Comment: Try removing the existing file using

`sudo rm -rf oracle-xe-11.2.0`

And then re-run the original command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the oracle-xe-11.2.0 from Disk1 folder and then run the following command

sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm